# Getting Facebook albums details in C#

Tags: c#, http, facebook-graph-api

I need help in C# http request for getting photo album name from graph api explorer. I tried . here is my code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi give Token " );
            return;
        }
        var FBtoken = textBox1.Text;
        var fb = new FacebookClient(FBtoken);

        dynamic result = fb.Get("me?fields=albums{name}");
        var name = result.albums.data.name;

        MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
```

here I tried to get album name to create a directory to save album photo.

Comment: Please share any code you've come up with so far so we can help you out.

Comment: this is not a place to get work done for free. please tell us exactly where you got stuck and what you have tried. if you want to hire someone, there are other platforms for that.

Comment: sorry . I was in hurry . Now check it @luschn

Comment: If you need more detail please let me know . I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY IT :

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("me/albums?fields=name");
foreach(dynamic album in result.data){....}
```